# Javascript Switch Case w/ Leaflet

Tags: javascript, json, switch-statement, leaflet, geojson

Using a javascript switch in order to assign fillColor by particular case value. The code is running and assigning value based on the first case, but doesn't run through the subsequent cases.

```js
var ElectionDistrictLayer = L.geoJson(QueensCC, {
  style: function(feature) {
    var fillColor = feature.properties.QnsCountyCommitteeList_Seat_Description;
    switch(fillColor)
    {
      case "Full":
        fillColor = "#94ff7c";
        break;
      case "1 Vacancy":
        fillColor: "#ffff20";
        break;
      case "Fully Vacant":
        fillColor: "#ff2020";
        break;
      default:
        fillColor: "Black";
        break;
    }
    return {color: "blue", weight: 0, fillColor: fillColor, fillOpacity: .6};
  }
}).addTo(mymap);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo: you use colon (:) in next cases, whereas you reassign with equal sign (=) in the first case.